# Munit test case fails when trying to mock sfdc endpoint

Tags: munit

I am trying to mock an sfdc-endpoint .But in my actual flow this endpoint return some value.When i am trying to return any value through mocking this endpoint it is throwing an exception as:

```
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression "payload.size()" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:202)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:154)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:133)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:215)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager$2.match(DefaultExpressionManager.java:476)
    at org.mule.util.TemplateParser.parse(TemplateParser.java:149)
    at org.mule.util.TemplateParser.parse(TemplateParser.java:126)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.parse(DefaultExpressionManager.java:472)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.parse(DefaultExpressionManager.java:431)
    at org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor.log(LoggerMessageProcessor.java:88)
    at org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor.process(LoggerMessageProcessor.java:67)
    at org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$5003da6e.CGLIB$process$1(<generated>)
    at org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$5003da6e$$FastClassByMUNIT$$60cdcd72.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.mule.munit.common.mp.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.invokeSuper(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.mule.munit.common.mp.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.process(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.mule.modules.interceptor.processors.AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$5003da6e.process(<generated>)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:97)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:109)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$1.process(Flow.java:82)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$1.process(Flow.java:77)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.process(Flow.java:76)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$bb7e3368.CGLIB$process$0(<generated>)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$bb7e3368$$FastClassByMUNIT$$45e5ae9e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.mule.munit.common.mp.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.invokeSuper(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.mule.munit.common.mp.MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.process(MunitMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.mule.modules.interceptor.processors.AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMessageProcessorInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$bb7e3368.process(<generated>)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.functional.FunctionalMunitSuite.runFlow(FunctionalMunitSuite.java:261)
    at mule_work_with_form.TestGetEmployeeFlow.validateEchoFlow(TestGetEmployeeFlow.java:56)
Caused by: org.mule.mvel2.PropertyAccessException: [Error: unable to resolve method: java.lang.String.size() [arglength=0]]
[Near : {... payload.size() ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1084)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:993)
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:343)
```

I am using Munit-3.5-m2 .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can not mock the connector.

You see, the exception is pointing to a MEL error when executing a MEL expression and it's complaining that whatever the payload is when reaching that expression it doesn't have a size() method.

It actually says that the payload is a string and that has not size method:

Caused by: org.mule.mvel2.PropertyAccessException: [Error: unable to resolve method: java.lang.String.size() [arglength=0]]
[Near : {... payload.size() ....}]

I reckon you're expecting that payload to be a list or a collection.

I'll start looking the error there.

If you still find problems with that please share the code of the failing test and the one of the flow trying to be tested.

HTH